# XML to XAML conversion

Tags: xml, xaml

We have about 1400 xml files which we use to store data around the look and feel of the controls used to load dynamically in winform applications. We want to convert these XML to XAML. Is there any easy way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xslt was invented for this purpose.

However, if you're not familiar with xslt and you already have .NET skills, then LINQ to XML has made manipulating XML extremely easy, so you could use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with xslt you will be able to handle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net 4  and the xml can be deserialised into .net objects then I'd suggest deserialising the XML and reserialising using Xaml - see here http://blogs.msdn.com/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-serialization-and-deserialization-using-xamlservices.aspx for how to use the System.Xaml namespace.

However I think xslt my be the fastesr approach otherwise